# Clone gitlab project that uses git lfs without giving password all the time

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

I decided to try git lfs on gitlab. I noticed that it doesn't work with ssh so I decided to use https for it. Push works just fine but when I tried to clone my project it asked me for a username and a password for **every** file.

That's kind of annoying. Is there any workaround to it?

---

### EDIT 2018

This problem persist, where the real solution?  There are a simple and direct recipe for it?

The links https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials and [git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial) have perhaps something, but no objective solution.

Situation described by my `git lfs env`,

```
git-lfs/2.4.0 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.8.3)
git version 2.7.4

LocalWorkingDir=
LocalGitDir=
LocalGitStorageDir=
LocalMediaDir=lfs/objects
LocalReferenceDir=
TempDir=lfs/tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=3
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
LfsStorageDir=lfs
AccessDownload=none
AccessUpload=none
DownloadTransfers=basic
UploadTransfers=basic
git config filter.lfs.process = "git-lfs filter-process"
git config filter.lfs.smudge = "git-lfs smudge -- %f"
git config filter.lfs.clean = "git-lfs clean -- %f"
```

and when I do `git clone https://github.com/myPrivate/project1`  the problem clonning process is **not complete** (bug), and was  **giving usernae and password all the time**...

Problems also when try to do credentials (see [issue #2223](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2223), etc.)

---

Trying report:

- `git config credential.helper` outputs nothing, empty message.
- `git config -f .lfsconfig lfs.url  https://github.com/myPrivate/MyProj1` accepts anything... So, is the browser URL or `.git` URL?
  After it the command `git add .lfsconfig` say *"fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"* in both cases (URL with or without .git)
- `git config credential.https://github.com/myPrivate/MyProj1 myusername` say *"fatal: not in a git directory"*, but of course, I need to clone first (!)..
- ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [git-lfs issue 993](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/993):

> Because the LFS server and the git server can be separate endpoints, it is possible that a user has permission for the git server but not the LFS server.
>
> In this case, if there is a credential manager installed, the credentials will not be reset, and LFS will use them on each subsequent request without ever invalidating them.

You should check your `git config credential.helper` output.
On Windows, it should be (with recent 2017-2018 Git releases) "manager".
Open the Windows Credential Manager and clear out or fix any GitHub credential entry.

Note: [issue 2349](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2349) points out that Git-LFS had a problem to ask for credentials (in absence of an helper), because of a [lack of pty/tty](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1192#issuecomment-321100378), but that has likely been fixed.

---

### Transtating to dummies

(consolidating the answer and the comments)

1. check `git --version`, if less tham *2.16*, install better as [instructions here using PPA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41357503/287948)
2. check your `git config credential.helper` output, if it is empty,
    execute this line: `git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret`
   ... Them check again your `git config credential.helper` output: need to be this `/usr/...`  path.
3. Cloning...

   3.1. (as commented) Do first: `git ls-remote https://github.com/myPrivate/MyProj1`... That should prompt for your GitHub username and password account. Repeat that command to check that the second times, it does not prompt you for anything.

   3.2. Do your usual `git clone` (with care remove the broken old with `sudo rm -r oldBrokenBadClone`)... Giving username-and-password once.

Final notes about tests in many UBUNTU LTS servers... Sometimes, when you cloned before this procedure you can't fix the problem (`git pull` erros like "git-credential-libsecret: not found"). The solution is to remove all old cloned repo (caution with `rm -rf`). Seemingly you can do `git config --global credential.helper`  any time, so, do it. Clone again — perhaps giving username-and-password  twice but will be fine after it.

Comment: The command `git config credential.helper` do nothing, no erro, no message.

Comment: @PeterKrauss then you need first to upgrade to Linux Git 2.16.2 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41357503/6309), then use libsecret as a credential helper, as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/q/42284674/6309

Comment: Hum... Make sense, but my version is not good?  *git version 2.7.4*  Ok will do it

Comment: No, after [PPA procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41357503/287948)  the same `git --version` result, 2.7.4.

Comment: @PeterKrauss because many fixes have been applied since 2.7.4, some of them regarding the credential helper.

Comment: @PeterKrauss No: https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa does include 2.16.2.

Comment: Opps sorry, delete, now new version! After `apt install git`

Comment: Back, after `git --version` = 2.16.2, I do `git config credential.helper`  but it do nothing, empty

Comment: @PeterKrauss That is expected: you need now to set it up to libsecret, as described in the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/42284674/6309

Comment: Hum... Do you have an UBUNTU script or command do it? Some simple and direct procedure?  I not understand how to do *"set it up to libsecret"*

Comment: @PeterKrauss That is where "as described in the question stackoverflow.com/q/42284674/6309" comes in: `git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret` (type it in a bash, in any folder, it does not matter)

Comment: Ok! Now the message of `git config credential.helper` is this path... so.. can I do my clone and it will work fine?

Comment: @PeterKrauss Do first: `git ls-remote https://github.com/myPrivate/MyProj1`: that should prompt for your GitHub username and password account. Repeat that command to check that the second times, it does *not* prompt you for anything. Finally, do your clone.

Comment: @PeterKrauss I have to call it a day, but I will follow-up tomorrow morning in a few hours.

Comment: @PeterKrauss It's not clear to me if this answer helped you solved the problem. If yes, please tell me to mark it as accepted answer :)

Comment: Hi @TheCrafter, yes, this answer (the 3 steps) was the best for me. See also [github.com/git-lfs issue #2040](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2040#issuecomment-373856317).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Git's [credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) which git lfs supports (has a permanent store and in-memory [cache](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/#platform-linux) options).

I also noticed git lfs had some [issues](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/issues/474) related to this which have been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If no password is required to actually access the files and you're accessing with an `https://server.com/path/to/repo` URL then it should work ([as of git-lfs 0.5.3](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/pull/415)). One possibility is that your configuration has `lfs.batch = false`.  Try `git -c lfs.batch=true clone https://server.com/path/to/repo` --- no credential helper required.

Comment: Hi @Paul, thanks!  But my testing process was completed, I can't  test your solution... See my consolidated instructions at "Transtating to dummies" in [the VonC's anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49244743/287948)

Comment: Hum... I see on my tests, before solution I tested `git -c lfs.batch=true clone`  but it not solved.