# Why git push of LFS git ask password 3 times?

Tags: git, large-files

I am using standard github.com repo in LFS mode, and it is working fine... But always, when I push, this 3xLogin occurs:

```
git push
Username for 'https://github.com': xpto
Password for 'https://xpto@github.com': 
Username for 'https://github.com': xpto
Password for 'https://xpto@github.com': 
Locking support detected on remote "origin". Consider enabling it with:
  $ git config 'lfs.https://github.com/xpto-org/xpto-prj.git/info/lfs.locksverify' true
Username for 'https://github.com': xpto
Password for 'https://xpto@github.com': 

Git LFS: (0 of 1 files) 3.38 MB / 925.18 MB
```

Comment: seems credential.helper was  a solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49244743/287948

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Add this to your `~/.ssh/config` file.

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
```

Start your ssh agent:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

Then add your key:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

*note* your key could be named differently.

Answer (score 1):

cache password to avoid this,you can also customize the time.visit link:
https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/caching-your-github-password-in-git