# General "git-credential-libsecret not found" error

Tags: git, credentials

The git repo have no LFS enabled, but I was prepared git to use in another clone, so use the `git config --global credential.helper` that seems the cause of the problem.

Seems [the same problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36585496/287948), but I am using updated `git` (v2.17.0), so it is not a version problem.

Exemple: after simple `git pull` the message is

```
/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret get: 1: 
/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret get: 
 /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret: 
 not found
```

---

NOTES

There are no `git-credential-libsecret` file,

```
sudo ls /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret
ls: cannot access '/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, make sure to understand where that setting is coming from

```
git config --show-origin -l
```

Then you can unset it.
For instance:

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

Once the situation is cleaned, you can install back `libsecret`, as described in "[How to bake credential into docker image for git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48237790/6309)".

Comment: Yes, fixed the basic problem (!)... But how to use `credential.helper` again?  I lost my credential, need to do something?  PS: after the `--unset`  the `--show-origin`  lost the line *credential.helper=/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret* of the file */root/.gitconfig*.

Comment: Check if https://stackoverflow.com/a/49244743/6309 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/48237790/6309 can help.

Comment: Thanks the `apt`  of the second link is helping, seem that all is working fine again.

Comment: @PeterKrauss Great, well done! I have edited the answer to make that step more visible.